# find $x$ where $x^3$ $\equiv$ $1\mod p$, given a primitive root modulo of $p$

Tags: number-theory

How to efficiently find $x$ where $x^3$ $\equiv$ $1\mod p$, given a primitive root of $p$ in the range of $[0,p-1]$?
$p$ is a prime.
Is is true that it only has three roots?
So if one of the primitive roots is given, how to efficient found all such x?

Comment: Are you given a "primitive root"? The phrase "a primitive modulo p" isn't familiar to me.

Comment: Oh , it  should be primitive root

Comment: Suggest you change it in the title also.

Comment: Then that would not be hard. If $p \not\equiv 1 \pmod3$ then only $x\equiv 1\pmod p$ is the solution; else the solutions are $x\equiv 1, g^{(p-1)/3}$ and $g^{2(p-1)/3} \pmod p$ where $g$ is the primitive root.

Comment: Is $p$ a prime?

Comment: But if only one of the g is given, how to find all such x?

Comment: OK, thanks.  I edited your post to change the capital "P" you used to a $LaTeX$ified "$p$. Hope this is OK.

Comment: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DiscreteLogarithm.html

Comment: Also:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_root_modulo_n

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $p$ is an odd prime $\equiv 1 \pmod{3}$ and $G=\mathbb{F}_p^*=\langle g\rangle $, then 
$$ x = g^{\frac{p-1}{3}},\quad x=g^{2\frac{p-1}{3}},\quad x=1 $$
are distinct solutions of $x^3\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ by Fermat's little theorem.
If $p$ is an odd prime $\equiv 2\pmod{3}$, the map $\varphi:G\to G$ given by $\varphi(x)=x^3$ is surjective (since invertible), hence 
$x^3\equiv 1\pmod{p}$ only has the trivial solution $x=1$.

Answer (score 0):

COMMENT (posted because is long for write as a comment).- There are three roots if and only if $p=3m+1$ and only a root if and only if $p=3m+2$.

Since $x^{p-1}-1=0$, if $x^3-1=0$ has three roots then
$\dfrac{x^{p-1}-1}{x^3-1}\in\mathbb F_p$ and if only one root (obviously equal to $1$) then $\dfrac{x^{p-1}-1}{x^3-1}\notin\mathbb F_p$.

**Examples**.-In $\mathbb F_{13}$ one has $\dfrac{x^{12}-1}{x^3-1}=(x^6+1)(x^3+1)$ and $x=1,3,9$

In $\mathbb F_{11}$ one has $\dfrac{x^{10}-1}{x^3-1}=x^7+x^4+x+\dfrac{1}{x^2+x+1}\notin\mathbb F_{11}[x]$ and just $x=1$